# Why Ridge and Lasso regression is returning almost identical results to Linear Regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, scikit-learn, lasso, ridge-regression

I was trying to compare Ridge, Lasso and Linear Regression models to each other. I am using a subset of the Ames housing dataset. Here is a [link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BexTuychiev/medium_stories/master/2021/february/7_ridge/data/train.csv) to an already preprocessed dataset that I am using. The problem I am having is that I am getting almost identical MAE and R2 scores across all three regressors.

I have chosen the `alpha` for Ridge and Lasso using `sklearn`'s `RidgeCV` and `LassoCV`. When I find the optimal values for `alpha`, my results are all the same:

```py
>>> lin_reg = LinearRegression()
>>> _ = lin_reg.fit(X_train, y_train)
>>> preds = lin_reg.predict(X_test)
>>> print("Training score:", lin_reg.score(X_train, y_train))
>>> print("Testing score:", lin_reg.score(X_test, y_test))
>>> print("MAE of Linear Regression:", mean_absolute_error(y_test, preds), '\n')
Training score: 0.8407611240459149
Testing score: 0.7150883693754784
MAE of Linear Regression: 22010.868252393684 


>>> ridge = Ridge(alpha=86)
>>> _ = ridge.fit(X_train, y_train)
>>> preds = ridge.predict(X_test)
>>> print("Training score:", ridge.score(X_train, y_train))
>>> print("Testing score:", ridge.score(X_test, y_test))
>>> print("MAE of Ridge Regression:", mean_absolute_error(y_test, preds), '\n')

Training score: 0.8394480895979937
Testing score: 0.709676899205446
MAE of Ridge Regression: 21846.657338724657 


>>> lasso = Lasso(alpha=56)
>>> _ = lasso.fit(X_train, y_train)
>>> preds = lasso.predict(X_test)
>>> print("Training score:", lasso.score(X_train, y_train))
>>> print("Testing score:", lasso.score(X_test, y_test))
>>> print("MAE of Lasso Regression:", mean_absolute_error(y_test, preds), '\n')

Training score: 0.8407132070277218
Testing score: 0.7147064148681453
MAE of Lasso Regression: 21963.710213405455
```

Why am I getting these results? It is clear that all 3 are overfitting, right? I mean, I am getting a much higher training score than test's. Even plotting the coefficients of trained models give very similar results:

[image]

What is the problem here? Shouldn't ridge and lasso at least shrink the coefficients?

Comment: Did you normalize your features? I don’t see that in the original ‘preprocessed’ dataset. Lasso and ridge regression depend on that to work properly.

Comment: This plot is unreadable because it has no labels or explanations: what does it purport to show?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Yes, all features are normalized.

Comment: The plot shows the values for coefficients which I obtained using `.coef_` attribute of each estimator @whuber

Comment: Yes, but you didn’t label the lines or the axes, as I requested when you posted this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: To what range did you normalize the features?

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I used `sklearn`'s `StandardScaler`. Also tried with `MinMaxScaler`, same results

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I fixed the plot, can you take a look again, please?

Comment: I don’t think your target variable has been normalized.

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't normalize it. How do I do it? I am sorry, I am fairly new to ML